# How to search for something like a declared value in Big Query SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

So I have `DECLARE` values in a query and I'm wondering how I would go about making it so I can search for something `LIKE` the name. So for example:

```
DECLARE Name STRING DEFAULT 'MI'

SELECT DISTINCT
  Employee,
  Pay,
  Date
FROM
  Temp_Table

WHERE
  Employee LIKE Name
```

When doing this, I get nothing when I know from the data I currently has, have multiple `MI` within the names. I have also tried doing:

```
WHERE
  Employee LIKE '%' + Name + '%'
```

But this is throwing an error of the following:

```
Query error: No matching signature for operator + for argument types: STRING, STRING. Supported signatures: INT64 + INT64; FLOAT64 + FLOAT64; NUMERIC + NUMERIC; DATE + INT64; INT64 + DATE
```

Is there anyway that I can search for something `LIKE` a `DECLARE` value? Or would I have to have the query without the `DECLARE` value?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: ANSI SQL has `str1 || str2` for concatenation. Some products have `concat(str1, str2)`.

Comment: ... and BigQuery supports both above

Comment: Perfect! That did it, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option - you can use REGEXP_CONTAINS as in below example

```
DECLARE Name STRING DEFAULT 'MI'

SELECT DISTINCT
  Employee,
  Pay,
  Date
FROM
  Temp_Table
WHERE
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(UPPER(employee), name);
```